# Error in broker list argument in Kafka Producer

Tags: docker, server, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I started a docker container from Wurstmeister Kafka with the command:

```
docker run -ti --name sender --entrypoint /bin/bash wurstmeister/kafka:latest
```

Then i use the command:

```
docker exec -ti <container_id> bash
```

to go inside the container.Once in bash, i try to set up a Kafka producer to send messages. The Kafka server resides in a vm in the cloud with public address 192.168.25.21. When i run the command inside the container:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.168.25.21:9092 --topic test
```

i get the error in the broker-list argument.The broker-list argument wants a string as an argument and it recognises the 192.168.25.21 as number. If i use the dns name of another server it works fine.However i want to be able to use the ip as described previously.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So, `--entrypoint /bin/bash` should put you in a terminal already, no reason to `exec -ti` again.

In any case, IPs should work fine, in my experience, but you're welcome to quote it `--broker-list '192.168.25.21:9092'`. However, I generally use an exported environment variable of a string for at least three broker addresses, then use that from any CLI tool rather than repeatedly copy and pasting an IP or host

BTW, not really seeing the need for Docker here. If you can't/won't install Java or the Kafka downloads themselves, `kafkacat` is a good alternative